# Print correct value from dropdown php (array)

Tags: php, html

I have tried to find a way to print the correct values from the dropboxes, but I just cant manage to get it working. I want the dropdownbox to write this: The last known currency for "BTC" is: "17" if I picked bitcoin. I would really appreciate your help big time!

```html
    <?php
$v2 = array(
    "BTC" => array(
        "navn" => "Bitcoin",
        "k1" => "1",
        "k2" => "11",
        "k3" => "17"
    ),
    "ETH" => array(
        "navn" => "Ethereum",
        "k1" => "2",
        "k2" => "12",
        "k3" => "27"
    ),
    "LTC" => array(
        "navn" => "Litecoin",
        "k1" => "3",
        "k2" => "13",
        "k3" => "37"
    ),
    "XMR" => array(
        "navn" => "Monero",
        "k1" => "4",
        "k2" => "14",
        "k3" => "47"
    ),
    "XRP" => array(
        "navn" => "Ripple",
        "k1" => "5",
        "k2" => "15",
        "k3" => "57"
    )
);
echo "<form action = 'valgtvaluta.php' method='post'><select name=''style='width: 200;'> >";
foreach($v2 as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=".$key.">".$key." ".$value['navn']."</option>";
}
echo "<input type='Submit'></select></form>";

$v2[$_POST['select']]['k3']

?>
```

Comment: Where does `B3` come from?

Comment: What is `$_POST['select']`? Did you mean to use `name='select'` for the dropdown?

Comment: K3 I mean, sorry

Comment: Shouldn't it be `17`?

Comment: Yes Barmar, Something like that, but I dont know how to integrate everything. Not sure if its correct...

Comment: Yes it should be 17 if bitcoin is picked, i just wanted the illustrate how I wanted to print it :)

Comment: Looks like you put the select tag inside the form tag. Move that outside of the form tag first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to the `<select>` that matches what you look for in `$_POST`.

`<input type="submit">` should not be inside the `<select>`.

Then check if the form was submitted, and echo what you want.

```
<?php
$v2 = array(
    "BTC" => array(
        "navn" => "Bitcoin",
        "k1" => "1",
        "k2" => "11",
        "k3" => "17"
    ),
    "ETH" => array(
        "navn" => "Ethereum",
        "k1" => "2",
        "k2" => "12",
        "k3" => "27"
    ),
    "LTC" => array(
        "navn" => "Litecoin",
        "k1" => "3",
        "k2" => "13",
        "k3" => "37"
    ),
    "XMR" => array(
        "navn" => "Monero",
        "k1" => "4",
        "k2" => "14",
        "k3" => "47"
    ),
    "XRP" => array(
        "navn" => "Ripple",
        "k1" => "5",
        "k2" => "15",
        "k3" => "57"
    )
);
echo "<form action = 'valgtvaluta.php' method='post'>
        <select name='select' style='width: 200;'>";
foreach($v2 as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=".$key.">".$key." ".$value['navn']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>
    <input type='Submit' name='submitbtn'>
    </form>";

if (isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
    echo "The last known value for {$_POST['select']} is {$v2[$_POST['select']]['k3']}";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barmar, but where should I put this name in? sorry for my bad understanding here.

Comment: I posted the entire code that replaces what you wrote.

Comment: Don't you see `<select name='select' style='width: 200;'>` in my answer?

Comment: Got it, thank you for the help Barmar! Thanks a lot!